# Set View Controller root in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I was using the [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) and Storyboards in my app and when I want to change the center view using `self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[TestViewController alloc] init];` I don't get the view on the center. But if I do the layout programmatically, I get the view.

So how do I init a view as root in Storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You initiate a view controller as a root. you do it by dragging the arrow inside the story board:

[image]